# Hide ONLY navigation bar and not status bar (on swipe) in iOS 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, uinavigationbar

How can I hide only the navigation bar and not the status bar, in the same way that Facebook does. Using `navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true` hides both. And so does `navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)`

I have a table view, and when the table is scrolled I would like the navigation bar to hide to leave more room for the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popping this in the app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` got me the same result. Then I just set `hidesNavigationBarsOnSwipe` to true in storyboard or in `viewWillAppear`

```
var view: UIView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.window!.rootViewController!.view.bounds.width, 20))
view.backgroundColor=UIColor(red: 32/255, green: 159/255, blue: 207/255, alpha: 1)
self.window?.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(view)
```